# Can a '.exe' file made through python run on another device with python language not installed?

Tags: python, exe

See, I made a python program with about 7 libraries being used and I converted it into a '.exe' file. So, I wondered if I could run this same file on another device with python not installed.

Is it possible?

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: That probably depends how you made it into a `.exe` file. But see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen) for the answer to your implied question

Comment: Vote Duplicate: [How can I make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you did it. [Pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) is a common one that allows you to do that.